# WordPress "unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/2019/10". ¿Es su directorio padre escribible por el servidor?

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, xampp

Estoy utilizando ***xampp*** desde un computador con *ubuntus* y no se si paso algo en la instalación pero cuando trato de subir imágenes me sale este error.

---

> wordpress unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/2019/10. is
>   its parent directory writable by the server?

---

Como dato extra no se si esta relacionado después de instalar *xampp* y antes de correrlo trate de montar un servidor de *sonarqube*, y ademas a la carpeta de `htdocs` y a la del proyecto están con permisos 755 pero no se ha dejado.

Answer (score 2):

El propietario del directorio de WordPress y el propietario del proceso httpd deben ser los mismos (i.e.daemon).

Por lo tanto, el propietario del directorio de WordPress debe cambiarse al mismo usuario que el proceso httpd.

**Mostrar al usuario del proceso httpd:**

1)   ps -aux| grep httpd

[image: ps -aux|grep httpd]

el usuario es "daemon"

**Cambie el propietario del directorio de wordpress al usuario del httpd (que es "daemon") :**

2) sudo chown -R daemon /opt/lampp/htdocs/wordpress/